# React-hook-form and react-select AsyncSelect: label from select not being shown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-select, react-hook-form

I'm working on a page with a form on edit mode. The form uses `react-hook-form`. On load I fetch some data from the backend (I'm using NextJs) and then assign the data to the elements in the form. The data returned from the backend is something like:

```
{
   "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "barcode": "2342343242343",
        "title": "ziggy 3",
        "slug": "ziggy-3",
        "artist": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Artist",
            "slug": "my-testArtist",
            "type": "solo",
            "countryOfOrigin": "US",
            "created_at": "2022-05-25T19:46:34-04:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-05-29T12:12:51-04:00",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "genre": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pop",
            "slug": "pop",
            "description": "Pop",
            "parent": 0,
            "active": true,
            "created_at": "2022-05-20T21:00:15-04:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-05-20T21:00:15-04:00",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "num_of_records": 1,
        "original_release_date": "2022-05-03",
        "reissue_release_date": "",
        "label": "",
}
```

On the form I've got a lookup field which was made using `react-select`:

```
<Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>Artist<span className={"required"}>*</span></Form.Label>
                            <Controller
                                name="artist_id"
                                control={control}
                                rules={{ required: true }}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <AsyncSelect
                                        {...field}
                                        isClearable
                                        defaultOptions
                                        placeholder={"Artist's name"}
                                        loadOptions={loadArtistOptions}
                                        onInputChange={handleArtistInputChange}
                                        cacheOptions
                                        getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
                                        getOptionValue={e => e.id}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
```

on load, I want to see the `artist_id` data to be populated in the `AsyncSelect` field.

To do so I've tried 2 things so far:

1. This is the definition of my functional component, notice it receives the record object:

```
export default function RecordForm({
    mode,
    record,
    submitFn,
                                   }) {

const { register, control, setValue, reset, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm();
    const [inputValue, setArtistValue] = useState('');
    const [genreInputValue, setGenreValue] = useState('');


    let tmpArtist = {};
    tmpArtist["value"] = record.artist["id"];
    tmpArtist["label"] = record.artist["name"];
```

and my `Select` component is:

```
<Controller
                                name="artist_id"
                                control={control}
                                rules={{ required: true }}
                                defaultValue={tmpArtist}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <AsyncSelect
                                        {...field}
                                        isClearable
                                        defaultOptions
                                        placeholder={"Artist's name"}
                                        loadOptions={loadArtistOptions}
                                        onInputChange={handleArtistInputChange}
                                        cacheOptions
                                        getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
                                        getOptionValue={e => e.id}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
```

Notice the addition of `defaultValue={tmpArtist}`.

2. Using `useEffect` and `react-hook-form`'s `setValue`:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (record) {
            tmpArtist["value"] = record.artist["id"];
            tmpArtist["label"] = record.artist["name"];
            setValue("artist_id", tmpArtist)
        }
    }, [record])
```

and my Select component:

```
<Controller
                                name="artist_id"
                                control={control}
                                rules={{ required: true }}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <AsyncSelect
                                        {...field}
                                        isClearable
                                        defaultOptions
                                        placeholder={"Artist's name"}
                                        loadOptions={loadArtistOptions}
                                        onInputChange={handleArtistInputChange}
                                        cacheOptions
                                        getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
                                        getOptionValue={e => e.id}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
```

notice the lack of `defaultValue`.

When I submit the form with either of the previously presented changes, I see that they're holding the passed value on load. For instance:

```
{
    "barcode": "3234423423121",
    "title": "Ten",
    "original_release_date": "2022-06-16",
    "num_of_records": "1",
    "reissue_release_date": "",
    "label": "",
    "sleeve_side_color": "#000000",
    "vinyl_color": "#000000",
    "owned_copies": "1",
    "catalog_number": "",
    "artist_id": {
        "value": 16,
        "label": "Pearl Jam"
    },
    "genre_id": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Rock",
        "slug": "rock",
        "description": "Rock",
        "parent": 0,
        "active": true,
        "created_at": "2022-05-22T14:51:54-04:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-05-22T14:51:54-04:00",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    "size": {
        "value": 12,
        "label": "12\""
    }
}
```

the previous object is what's being submitted. As you can see the `artist_id` object contains the value the form was loaded with.

BUT I don't see this value being selected in the UI. The component in the UI looks like:

[image]

As you can see it is blank, even though the underline data seems to be correctly set because the artist data is being submitted.

How can I make the `Select` component to display the label on load?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, so here's what I've found in case anyone faces the same issue. Using option 1 from the 2 options posted above:

```
let tmpArtist = {};
    tmpArtist["value"] = record.artist["id"];
    tmpArtist["label"] = record.artist["name"];


...

<Controller
                                name="artist_id"
                                control={control}
                                rules={{ required: true }}
                                defaultValue={tmpArtist}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <AsyncSelect
                                        {...field}
                                        isClearable
                                        defaultOptions
                                        placeholder={"Artist's name"}
                                        loadOptions={loadArtistOptions}
                                        onInputChange={handleArtistInputChange}
                                        cacheOptions
                                        getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
                                        getOptionValue={e => e.id}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
```

I've replaced:

```
getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
getOptionValue={e => e.id}
```

by:

```
getOptionLabel={e => e.label}
getOptionValue={e => e.value}
```

and now the field is being populated and the value is also being submitted.

[image]